# Wrong XML encoding tag written by WriteStartDocument

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I've set the XMLWriter to use the UTF8 encoding, but the WriteStartDocument method still writes a UTF16 tag.

This is the part of the code:

```
            m_sbXML = New System.Text.StringBuilder

            m_xmlWriterSettings = New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
            With m_xmlWriterSettings
                .Indent = True
                .IndentChars = "    "
                .Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            End With

            m_xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(m_sbXML, m_xmlWriterSettings)

            Call m_xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
```

It should write the document tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

but instead it writes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are writing to a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). Strings in .NET are always UTF-16 encoded.

If you want to create an UTF-8 encoded XML file, write to a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx).

*Example:*

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = True,
    IndentChars = "    ",
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion using a memory stream, but I prefer to use the StringBuilder. If needed I'll use UTF16 if that solves the problem, but although the document tag seems to be fine, opening the XML in f.e. IE results in an error saying: "Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported. ...."

Comment: The error is likely because you are saving resulting string as UTF-8. Your choice - use StringBuilder than save string as UTF-16, or use Stream and specify any encoding.

Comment: I have tested using UTF16, but that doesn't solve the IE error as described above.

Comment: For now I've solved it by using one of the work-around as described in this page: http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/tip-force-utf8-or-other-encoding-for-xmlwriter-with-stringbuilder/